# Python: changing string values in lists into ascii values

Tags: python, string, list, append, ascii

I'm trying to convert characters in a string into individual ascii values. I can't seem to get each individual character to change into its relative ascii value.

For example, if variable words has the value ["hello", "world"], after running the completed code the list ascii would have the value :

[104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]

So far I've got:

```
words = ["hello", "world"]
ascii = []
for x in words:
    ascii.append(ord(x))
```

printing this returns an error as ord expect a character but gets a string. Does anyone know how i can fix this to return the ascii value of each letter? thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat words as one long string instead (using a nested list-comp for instance):

```
ascii = [ord(ch) for word in words for ch in word]
# [104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]
```

Equivalent to:

```
ascii = []
for word in words:
    for ch in word:
        ascii.append(ord(ch))
```

If you wanted to do them as separate words, then you change your list-comp:

```
ascii = [[ord(ch) for ch in word] for word in words]
# [[104, 101, 108, 108, 111], [119, 111, 114, 108, 100]]
```

Comment: what if i wanted to print the ascii variable as two seperate lists?e.g. [[104, 101, 108, 108, 111], [119, 111, 114, 108, 100]]

Answer (score 1):

Your loop iterates over the `words` list which is a list of `string`. Now, `ord` is a function that will return the integer ordinal of a one-character string. So you need the iterate over the characters of the string also.

```
words = ["hello", "world"]
ascii = []
for word in words:
    ascii.extend(ord(ch) for ch in word)
```

`print ascii` will give you,

```
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]
```